# NULL POINTER in com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage

Tags: java, email

I'm trying to send email with attachment using SMTP protocol. Also I added `activation.jar` (v. 1.1.1) as Maven dependency and javax.mail dependency (v. 1.4.7). And I have got configs in xml that works for messages without attachments.
Here is my code

```
 public boolean sendEmail(Form form) {
    try {
        Properties props = getProperties();
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
        MimeMultipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");

        MimeBodyPart contentPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        contentPart.setText("Email Body", "UTF-8");

        multiPart.addBodyPart(contentPart);

        MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        attachmentPart.setContent(form.getCvFile(), "application/pdf");


        attachmentPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);

        attachmentPart.setFileName(form.getFile().getName());

        multiPart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
        mimeMessage.setContent(multiPart);
        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

It gives me `NullPointer`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:557)
    at com.my.sender.EmailSender.sendEmail(EmailSender.java:59)
    at com.my.controller.SpringController.update(SpringController.java:133)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:105)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletExceptionAdapter.service(ServletExceptionAdapter.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.FilterExceptionAdapter.doFilter(FilterExceptionAdapter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:70)
```

Comment: show SpringController.update method

Comment: @MikeAdamenko, its  a line where i'm invoking my sendMessage method